# How to make the field in reactive form to be in read only state in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form, where in i have used form array and all, but now i just need to fetch the details and must make that read only.
 i have tried with [readonly]="true" also but it didnt work with select. so can anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

use `[disabled]="true"`

```
<select  [disabled]="true" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" formControlName="Relationship">
<option *ngFor="let relation of relations" [value]="relation.StatusId">{{relation.Description}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you that worked but is there anyway in reactive forms so that whole form can be disabled?

Comment: this.form.controls['Relationship'].disable();

Comment: i need to disable for all the fields, i will put my code

Comment: then add this for each form controls like @Robin mentioned

Comment: i have added my get function please check

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from ts file while creating form control like

```
this.bookForm = this.fb.group({
          id: null,
          title: [{ value: '', disabled: true }]
            });
```

Comment: i havent used formGroup in that way

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like `this.emergencyContactForm.get('Phone').disable();`

Comment: where should i write that?

Comment: In your `.ts` file where you create your formgroup.